# Linking mojos in Maven

Tags: maven, build-process, maven-plugin

I'm using the maven cargo plugin to remotely deploy a servlet in tomcat. When I make updates to the code I have to run two mojos, one for compiling a new war (`package`), and one for deploying the war remotely (`cargo:deployer-redeploy`).

I want to be able to simply invoke `cargo:deployer-redeploy` and it invokes the compilation of the source code and creation of a new war and deploys that remotely. Essentially I want the redeploy mojo to be dependant on the package mojo (in `ant` terminology).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just bind the cargo plugin to a later phase than `package` (e.g. `verify`), so in the plugin's configuration section in the pom, put something like:

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>redeploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

When you run `mvn verify` it will run the war plugin (as part of `package`) then cargo.